# Steal app and post it on AppStore using ad-hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, testing, app-store, adhoc

I am going to ask users on public forums to take part in my app beta testing using ad-hoc method. So if user interested in testing/reviewing he sends me UUID and I send him app binary.

The main question: is it safe to give anyone app binary file? I heard some terrible stories on Apple iphone developer forums that some guy found his app published someone else using another company name and different icon. So the app was absolutely the same except company name and graphics. He told that someone else got his app binary, cracked it and post it on appstore for profit.

So is it possible to steal my app and publish it on appstore if I give my app binary using ad-hoc?

thx

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as it is possible for the same to occur for apps that are in the app store.

There are tools that can unpack the signed binaries which can then be repacked.

In the same light, someone could crack Visual Studio to show a different company name and then release it as their own.

In both cases, there are serious legal ramifications, and in both cases it is actually very rare to occur.

In the case of iPhone apps, it is very unlikely someone would want to bother stealing your app.  If you really think there is a risk, I wouldn't recommend sending ad-hoc copies to random people you don't know.

Comment: I am worried about that because my app is not on appstore yet. When someone steal and publish it he will be the first with it on appstore  and I'll will be the second. In that case it gonna be harder to claim that I am the original developer and usually the first is gain more profit then the second :)

Comment: But you have the source code to prove you wrote it.  The other party only has object files.  I am sure you wouldn't have too hard a time convincing Apple to pull theirs off of the app store.  Besides, one update later, you're ahead of that competitor.

Answer (score 1):

While it is technically possible, (IANAL) I believe such an act is a violation of the DMCA, giving you legal ground to go after them, any and all profits they make off of what they stole, etc.

Comment: It would also be a copyright violation, which has much more established and tested laws associated with it as well as many lawyers who specialize in copyright violations.

Also, copyright is a civil matter (you sue and collect damages) DMCA is not.

While the copyright law would definitely be the most likely scenario for seeking damages, with something on the scale of an iPhone game you'd be very unlikely to gain anything, and your biggest hope is likely having the app pulled from the app store, possibly with a Cease and Desist notice.

IANAL, but I do pretend to be one when no one is looking.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel that threatened, you can add an "expiration system" to your app. Check if the date is later that, say November 2009 and kill it. I don't think someone will go into the trouble of removing your code signing, signing it with his own identity after he has cracked the expiration failsafe. You app should be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of code that can't be decompiled/disassembled. I guess this applies to iPhone as well. So yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically they can take the binary and resign it using their keys. They could do that either to install it on their device, or submit it to the store.

They won't have the source, so making any sort of fixes or changes (including to deal with a submission rejection) would be remarkably difficult, and it should not be to hard to prove a copyright violation and get it taken down (though you might need to pay some lawyers).

At the end of the day I wouldn't worry about it... this sort of thing just doesn't happen in practice.